# Removing large files from an old git commit?

Tags: git

Without thinking, I managed to commit a bunch of massive audio files in a github commit. I only copped this about 7 commits later, when it was time to push.

I quickly rm --cache'd the audio files, and added them to gitignore - but since they were added around 7 commits earlier, hitting git push means git is still trying to package and send these 3-4gb of files up, which is resulting in the push failing.

Is there any way to prevent these files from being sent at all, without reverting back 7 commits to when I initially started tracking them?

Comment: This is what `filter-branch` is for. You might be able to interactively-rebase them out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: Sorry, to be clearer - it's around 3-4GB worth of *small* files. Around 10mb or so each. Running a catch-all "kill everything bigger than 100mb" doesn't do anything for me here. Everything's residing under one folder, I'm just trying to kill that folder in particular for the last 7~ commits.

Comment: Thanks @phd - running the BFG Repo tool on the given folder killed it off safely. I can push and merge again!